# How to jump to album in iOS 8.4 Music app?

Tags: iphone, music, ios

I've updated to iOS 8.4, and on the revamped Music app, I can't jump to artist. In previous versions, I could be playing a shuffle playlist and whenever I'm on some song and I wanted to keep playing from that album, I could simply tap the top right button and it would jump me to the currently playing song's album. Now, when I'm playing a song in a shuffle playlist, I see that button has been placed next to seek controls (previous, play/pause, next buttons), but when I tap that, it doesn't take me to the album anymore, it takes me to playlist.

How can I jump to album when playing a song from shuffle? It was a feature that I was using passively, but now I can't find it and I'm having quite hard time jumping to song's album, which I did *a lot*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The currently playing song shows up in a horizontal now playing bar.

   [image]
2. Click the three dots on the right hand side of the bar.

   [image]
3. Click on the album name at the top of the pop up menu.

   [image]

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that album art was tappable. Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Yeah this was a neat trick I learned after being frustrated by the same issue. Tapping on the artist name in that menu will take you to the artist page. However, there seems to be a bug where sometimes it'll redirect you to an "Unknown Artist" page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug "Unknown Album" if you do that on an Apple Music track.

Comment: ran into this topic looking to see if anyone else had this issue.  Thanks.